Order of the output with simplification
How can I force mathematica to write the output of the following expression in the correct order? Also, how is to multiply the constant pre-factor by the terms inside the bracket?
Input
1/6 (( {
      {a, b, c}
     } ).( {
      {1, \[Alpha], \[Beta]},
      {\[Alpha], 1, \[Gamma]},
      {\[Beta], \[Gamma], 1}
     } ).( {
      {a},
      {b},
      {c}
     } )) // Simplify

output
{{1/6 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2 a (b \[Alpha] + c \[Beta]) + 
     2 b c \[Gamma])}}

I want
{{ 1/6a^2 + 1/6b^2 + 1/6c^2 + 1/3 a b \[Alpha] + 1/3 a c \[Beta]) + 
     1/3 b c \[Gamma])}}


$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = 1/
     6  (({{a, b, c}}) . ({{1, α, β}, {α, 
         1, γ}, {β, γ, 1}}) . ({{a}, {b}, {c}})) //
    Simplify;

To keep the fractions separate you need to use HoldForm
(expr2 = (expr // Expand) /. 
    z : Rational[x_, y_] :> HoldForm[z ]) // TraditionalForm

(* (1/6 a^2+1/3 α a b+1/3 a β c+1/6 b^2+1/3 b c γ+1/6 c^2) *)

EDIT: More succinctly
(expr2 = (expr // Expand) /. 
    z_Rational :> HoldForm[z]) // TraditionalForm

(* same output *)
Releasing the hold gives
expr2 // ReleaseHold

(* {{a^2/6 + b^2/6 + c^2/6 + (a b α)/3 + (a c β)/3 + (b c γ)/3}} *)

